# OpenGL: Drawing a 1920 * 1080 quad = -5000 FPS?

Tags: opengl

Am I doing something wrong here?

I am drawing a quad over the whole screen with `glRectf( -1, -1, 1, 1 )`

Per rect the FPS of my program go down by roughly 5000.

- What is happening?

This is my OpenGL initialization:

```
  glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
  glLoadIdentity();
  glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );
  glOrtho( 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1 );
  glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
  glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
```

Comment: That's a big quad. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's a general test - I'll have to draw several quads of similar size per frame; e.g.: background, terrain, objects in a game

Comment: What is your OpenGL implementation?

Comment: Unless you like pure speculation, make a working testcase and tell us which OpenGL version you target, as well as the model of your graphics card. This code snippet tells us nothing.

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong, that's a big quad.

Answer (score 6):

1920x1080 is a lot of pixels. 7-11 fps seems pretty fast for the code snippet suggested by Travis G:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    glRectf(-1, -1, 1, 1);
```

Let's do the math:

1920 * 1080 * 1000 * 11 pixels / 1 second = 22.8 Gpix/s

Wikipedia has tables of headline figures for ATI cards here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units and for nVidia cards here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units

I'm going to guess you have a Radeon HD 5850 just because they're popular and the numbers fit (the 5850 apparently has 23 Gpix/s fillrate)

Answer (score 2):

If `glRectf(-1, -1, 1, 1)` is the only thing you are doing, then you are experiencing a bad case of premature framerate freakout.  Shawn Hargreaves covers this very nicely on [his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/05/20/a-tale-of-many-haggis.aspx).

The fact is that it takes quite some time to spin up the graphics pipeline and draw a frame.  As compared to not drawing anything (as I suspect you are doing), the framerate is going to drop by a huge amount, since doing *anything* is much more expensive than doing *nothing*.

To test my hypothesis, try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    glRectf(-1, -1, 1, 1);
```

Then see if your framerate changes at all.  It probably won't.

Comment: I have seriously tested this, right now. I get 7 to 11 FPS. I'm not kidding!

Comment: Also, I have tested drawing small to mid-sized polygons as well as quads before - there is no noticeable change in the FPS rate. However, as the covered area on the screen gets bigger than 50% the FPS start dropping by 1000 per 10% area covered.

Comment: I'm guessing your performance problems still lie outside of drawing the quad.  Perhaps post some more code in your question?

Comment: This is basically everything. I have tested it with and without drawing the full-screen quad. I have tried drawing small quads, which resulted in nearly no change in the original, high FPS. The FPS rate drops similarily when I draw two polygons which together cover the whole screen.

Comment: Well, you're certainly doing more than initialization ;-).  But I tried this on my computer just to be sure and it works with excessive speed.

Comment: A side note: I am using Delphi with SDL as window manager for OpenGL

Comment: Hmm...I just did a quick one-off in C, although I'm just as confused as you are.  Perhaps it's your graphics card?  Or something Delphi is doing?